# Could I use START TRANSACTION in sp for creating explicit transaction in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

Could I use START TRANSACTION in sp for creating explicit transaction in postgresql?

sample:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc1(
    input1 integer,
    input2 integer,
    INOUT output1 integer DEFAULT 0)
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $$
BEGIN 
    BEGIN 
        START TRANSACTION ;
        insert into table1 
        values(input1,input2);
        COMMIT  ;   
    END;    
END;
$$;
```

When calling sp, raise an error like below:

> ERROR: unsupported transaction command in PL/pgSQL

Comment: START TRANSACTION is not valid: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-transactions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot explicitly start a transaction inside a stored procedure, and it would not make any sense either, because there is already a transaction that was started when you called the procedure.

What makes sense, and what you can do, is to terminate the current transaction and start a new one with either

```
COMMIT AND CHAIN
```

or

```
ROLLBACK AND CHAIN
```

Comment: For chain any example link could you provide? this link doesnt look enough: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-commit.html @Laurenz Albe

Comment: I have no better link... what is unclear?

Comment: If I run this statement: `begin
insert into table1
values('a');
COMMIT AND CHAIN;`

Comment: Then your transaction is committed, and you have started a new transaction with the same isolation level as before. Since the old transaction was not read-only, the new one isn't either.